# how to write presistent cookie and fill with value from queryString

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, cookies

I'm a bit rasty with JQuery.

I want to add affiliate system to some website.
This website has "friends referaal bonus" program.

I want the site to log people I brought to the site
and add my name in the relevant field on the booking form.

this was my logic:

1) I will publish link like `theWebSite.com\?referral=eladbdv`
then JS will identify the query strin "referral" and will write the value "eladbdv" to a cookie on the website.

2) when the user navigate to the booking page, the site will read the value from the cookie and will fill the "howhear" field with "eladbdv".

Tried to suggest this JS code.
Am I missing something? Have any suvire logic error?

http://jsfiddle.net/Us8vR/

Comment: what is your problem i can't see any error in your code

Comment: no error. just verifying